# Dynamically reducing the size of thumbnails to evenly occupy space

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to lower the size of thumbnails to get them to evenly fit across the page, but still be as large as possible without going over a particular width.

This following code is the closest I've been able to achieve, it's problem is that at certain widths, it doesn't completely occupy the entire width.

I'm going to assume this is due to my less-than-adequate understanding of mathematics, can someone help? (Also I'm not particularly familiar with Javascript).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .thumb {
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: green;
                margin: 4px;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="thumbnails"><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div><div class="thumb"></div></div>

        <script>
            var resizeThumbnails = function() {
                var w = $('#thumbnails').width();
                var thumbsPerRow = w / 208;
                var thumbDiffer = 208 - (thumbsPerRow % 1) * 208;
                var thumbSize = 208 - (thumbDiffer / Math.floor(thumbsPerRow));
                var thumbSize = thumbSize - 8;
                $("#thumbnails .thumb").width(thumbSize).height(thumbSize);
            }
            $(window).resize(resizeThumbnails);
            $(window).ready(resizeThumbnails);
            resizeThumbnails();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var resizeThumbnails = function() {
    var w = $('#thumbnails').width();
    var thumbsPerRow = Math.ceil(w / 208);
    var thumbSize = Math.floor(w / thumbsPerRow) -8;
    $("#thumbnails .thumb").width(thumbSize).height(thumbSize);
}
```

Work out how many thumbnails you can fit on a row by dividing container width by thumbnail width and round up (because we're adding extra an extra thumbnail in order to resize the others down). Recalculate thumbnail size based on number per row.